# Question on entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

**Question**: let $f$ be an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$ and let $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar{z})}$ then which of the following **is/are** correct?

**(a)** if $f(z) ∈\mathbb{R}$ for all $z∈\mathbb{R}$ then $f=g$

**(b)** if $f(z)∈\mathbb{R}$  for all $z∈\{z : Im\text{ $z$ }=0\}∪\{z : Im\text{ $z$ }=a\}$ for some $a>0$ then $f(z+ ia)=f(z-ia)$ for all $z∈\mathbb{C}$

**(c)** if $f(z)∈\mathbb{R}$  for all $z∈\{z : Im\text{ $z$ }=0\}∪\{z : Im\text{ $z$ }=a\}$ for some $a>0$ then $f(z+ 2ia)=f(z)$ for all $z∈\mathbb{C}$

**(d)** if $f(z)∈\mathbb{R}$  for all $z∈\{z : Im\text{ $z$ }=0\}∪\{z : Im\text{ $z$ }=a\}$ for some $a>0$ then $f(z+ ia)=f(z)$ for all $z∈\mathbb{C}$

**My attempt**: clearly, if $z∈\mathbb{R}$ then $\bar{z}=z∈\mathbb{R}$. Hence if $f(z)∈\mathbb{R}$ then $f(\bar{z})=f(z)∈\mathbb{R}$ so that $g(z)=\overline{f(\bar{z})}=f(\bar{z})=f(z)$ for $z$ in $\mathbb{R}$ hence (a) is correct.

But as beginner i am **unable** to prove or discard (b), (c), (d). I am stuck on this from hours, Please help me..

Comment: It is easy to show that (b) and (c) are equivalent (just choose $z'=z+ia$). (d) is easily disproved using the exponential function and $a=\pi$.

Comment: @celtschk celtschk sir, OK if (b) and (c) are equivalent, But how to prove then (b) is true/false? Because as they are equivalent then, we need to prove one of them is true/false. Sir please help me.

Comment: The condition in (b) is a special case of the condition in (a). What can you say about where $g$ is real, and its values there?

Comment: Sir didn't get your last comment. Please elaborate.... further is my attempt of (a) is fine?

Comment: Note that I edited the comment; maybe you've seen the pre-edit version. And yes, your treatment of (a) is fine.

Comment: When $g(z)$ is real then $g(z)=\overline{g(z)}$?. Sorry still didn't get your hint sir

Comment: Samajla na mitra? :D

Comment: Haha.. yes got it. Thank you so much sir..and thank you celtschk sir too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will show that $(b)$ and $(c)$ are true.

From solving option $(a)$ you found that $f(z)=g(z)=\overline{f(\bar z)} \; \; \forall z \in \Bbb C$

Now in option $(b)$ note that $\{z : \text{Im} (z)=0\}=\Bbb R.$ Let $x \in \Bbb R$, then $f(x+ia)=\overline{f(\overline{x+ia})}=\overline{f(x-ia)}$. But $f(z) \in \Bbb R$ on $\{z : \text {Im}(z)=a\}$ as well. $\therefore f(x+ia)=\overline{f(x-ia)}\ \in \Bbb R \Rightarrow f(x+ia)=f(x-ia) \in \Bbb R.$
By identity theorem, $f(z+ia)=f(z-ia) \; \forall \; z \in \Bbb C.$

For option $(c)$, put $z=w+ia$ then you get $f(w+2ia)=f(w) \; \forall \; w \in \Bbb C$.